# Find limit: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: limits

Can someone help me find this limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}}$$.

I thought about substituting polar coordinates. But I think thats an overshot. Can someone please help here.

Comment: Try various lines of approach, $y=mx$ as $x\to0$

Comment: How is using polar coordinates "overkill"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar coordinates are not needed. Your function is:
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2} $$
hence along the line $y=x$ the limit equals $2$ while along the line $y=-x$ the limit equals $0$.

They do not match, hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: Why not $y=-x$? with such a cute factorization...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: you're right, it is definitely easier.

Answer (score 4):

Use polar coordinates

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\{}\\y=r\sin\theta\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\;\;\;\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^2(1+\sin2\theta)}{r^2}=1+\sin2\theta$$

and the above depends on the angle, thus the limit doesn't exist.

**Another way:** Choose first $\;y=x\;$ :

$$\frac{4x^2}{2x^2}=2$$

and now choose $\;y=-x\;$ ...well, you get the picture.

Comment: So after doing y=-x, I get 2. So that means the limit is 2?

Comment: @danny No, of course not. That's the limit along the line $\;y=x\;$ . What do you get along the line $\;y=-x\;$ ?  Zero !  But we know the limit, **if it exists at all**, *must* be independent from the path we choose to reach it, so...

Comment: @danny : He didn't check and got unlucky. Try $y=0$ ; you get $1$ as a ratio. EDIT : I didn't check either, but now I did ; you should have gotten $0$ with $y=-x$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Are you sure "he" didn't check? And no: not "either" ...:)

Comment: @Timbuc : Haha, something funny happened, right? :P

Comment: Yup...;) Perhaps it'd be a good idea to erase our above last comments as the OP seems to be a little confused about this matter and that can contribute to its confusion.

Comment: For the polar coordinate method, we let r go to 0 and find the limit of 1+sin2$\theta$, right?

Comment: @danny Indeed so, yet in this case we're left without any $\;r\;$ at all...

Comment: So what does that mean?

Comment: That the limit is $\;1+\sin2\theta\;$ , and it depends on the angle $\;\theta\;$ , and thus it doesn't exist. You know this, right?

Comment: ...and after you ask all those follow up questions which I duely address and you got my answer with **two** possible ways to solve it, you choose an answer that came 5 minutes after mine and it is **IDENTICAL** with one of my options...funny.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: try $x=1/n,y=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$ and $x=y=1/n$